# Alternatives for daily task

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-automation

First off, let me say I'm an Azure newb. I'm coming from the AWS world so I don't know the best routes in this new platform yet.

I want to write a task, let's assume it will be a PowerShell script, which will run once a day, at a scheduled time. The actual task shouldn't take more than a minute to finish each day.

One important aspect of this task is that it needs access to my company's internal hosts. There's a VPN setup in Azure, so I can configure any VM I want and it will be able to reach those servers.

I was hopeful I could use Azure Functions but I doubt I'll have the ability to configure networking in that service.

Then I start looking into Azure Automation and looks like I should be able to build something that wakes up a VM and the VM could possibly run the task at startup then shut itself off when done. Before I go that route I'd like to know I'm not missing something easier.

My goal is to create a repeatable pattern that myself and others in my group could create several of these infrequent, quick tasks without needing a VM running idle for pretty much the entire day.

Answer (score 1):

If you set up an Azure Function using the Application Service Plan (Not the Consumption Plan), you will have access to VNET Integration that allows you to set up a point-to-site VPN.

`Function App > Platform Features > Networking > Networking > VNET Integration`

[image: VNET Integration]

Comment: Would that only charge per execution or will it require an always-on VM?

Comment: Consumption Plan is the one that charges per execution. This would require an App service plan, which basically is a dedicated vm. Here is the pricing: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/

Comment: Thank you. As I said, I'm trying to find a good way to only pay roughly for each execution and at the same time have more control over the execution environment. Maybe I'll have to automate the VM lifecycle after all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Automation for this, you can do this with a combination of  running a Cloud job and running in a Hybrid Worker for this.

First you set up the Azure VM as a Hybrid Worker.

This is the documentation of the Hybrid Worker.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker

Then basically you can have a combination of a parent runbook(script) which runs in the cloud, start the Azure VM when you want to run something in it ( using Start-AzureVM) wait for some time in the runbook for the VM to start and then when it has started run your PowerShell script on the Azure VM using the Start-AzureAutomationRunbook cmdlet using the RunOn parameter ( see below )

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Azure/Start-AzureAutomationRunbook?view=azuresmps-4.0.0

Then you can shutdown the VM from the parent runbook. ( Stop-AzureVM)

This is a pattern which many of Azure Automation customers use.

Comment: Wouldn't this approach require a new server on my data center? The "Hybrid Runbook Worker"? I'm really trying to move this task to Azure. If I need to add a new server in my DC I think I'd prefer to simply run the task right there using Task Scheduler. Maybe this is a much harder problem than I thought.